# Is there any apache module which logs long running requests

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to check which request are taking more time in my Apache server.

Is there any Apache module or any mechanism which will allow `httpd` to log those requests that take a longer time to complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just log the time...
http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/06/apache-logs-how-long-does-it-take-to-serve-a-request/

Then filter the log yourself later for those taking too long.

Comment: This works like a charm.